# Plotting an equation from string form - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphing

I have an expression like this:

```
x = [40 50];
expression = -2.254443e-02*x^4 + 1.797023e+02*x^3 + -5.364190e+05*x^2 + 7.107614e+08*x + -3.527500e+11;
```

Now how do I plot this?

```
plot(x, expression)
```

Causes errors.

Comment: What errors does it give? Also are you sure you want x^n not x.^n? And where is the string form actually?

Comment: I don't think its a problem with . operators, because the error is - error using plot - error in color/linetype argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ezplot` to plot from an expression string:

```
x = [40 50];
expression = '-2.254443e-02*x^4 + 1.797023e+02*x^3 + -5.364190e+05*x^2 + 7.107614e+08*x + -3.527500e+11';
ezplot(expression, x);
```

**Please note** the addition of single quotes around the expression to turn it into a string!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with  Trilarion:

```
x = [40 50];
expression = -2.254443e-02*x.^4 + 1.797023e+02*x.^3 + -5.364190e+05*x.^2 + 7.107614e+08*x + -3.527500e+11;
plot( x, expression )
```

[image: plot]

Works for me.

If I use:

```
>> expression = -2.254443e-02*x^4 + 1.797023e+02*x^3 + -5.364190e+05*x^2 + 7.107614e+08*x + -3.527500e+11;
   ??? Error using ==> mpower
   Matrix must be square.
```

Which makes sense, because `x` is a (row)vector.  If you copy paste exactly the above, what do you get?